# Маршрутизация  для CentOS 6

Tags: маршрутизация, centos, сеть

[Уже задавал аналогичный вопрос,](http://admin.hashcode.ru/questions/1028/) но ответ не совсем то, поэтому несколько видоизменю его.  **В какой файл нужно добавить маршруты, чтобы при перезагрузке/вкл-выкл ПК они, т.е маршруты, оставались и загружались автоматом.**, т.е. чтоб были по дефолту?

Система СentOS 6 , подключение к сети через VPN. При вводе через терминал все работает, нареканий не имею, но уже маленько поднадоело постоянно вводить эти маршруты, поскольку это вызывает некоторое неудобство.

Answer (score 1):

> `Static route configuration is stored in a /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-interface file. For example, static routes for the eth0 interface would be stored in the /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-eth0 file. The route-interface file has two formats: IP command arguments and network/netmask directives.`

Странно, что Вы  гугл не спросили, на сайте дистрибутива все подробно расписано.

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку.Ходил вокруг да около да не дошел.Обидно,что догадывался,пробовал но в последний момент начинал сомневаться и откатывал назад. А насчет google,а зачем-же тогда мы здесь!?

Comment: Все оказалось значительно проще - создал файл /etc/sysconfig/network- scripts/route-eth1 (связь у меня через eth1),выставил ему права на выполнение,внес необходимые данные,подкорректировал файл ifup-routes, и... чудо,все сохраняется и работает. Спасибо всем кто помогал в этом вопросе. Осталось найти как сделать кнопку запуска для файла pppd /etc/ppp/peers/call xxxx от root. Может кто подскажет?

Answer (score 0):

как сделать кнопку запуска смотрите [тут](http://admin.hashcode.ru/questions/1116/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F)